# Proof that $\log \frac n {n-1} \gt \frac 2 {2\,n - 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have come across this inequality and checked with examples that it is true in the range that interests me (i.e. $n \ge 2$) and that, in addition, $\frac 2 {2\,n-1}$
seems to be the limit of $\log \frac n {n-1}$.

If I use the simple inequality that comes from comparing the logarithm function with the harmonic series, I get

$\log \frac n {n-1} = \int_{n-1}^n \frac 1 x\ d\,x \gt \frac 1 n$

But this does not lead me anywhere, because $\frac 2 {2\,n - 1} \gt \frac 2 {2\,n}$.

So I'm interested in a proof of this inequality.

Comment: Oops! Error in the question, I'm going to correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Edited to specify the range of interest for $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n > 1$ and the natural logarithm we have
$$
 \log \frac{n}{n-1} = \int_{n-1}^n \frac{dx}{x} > \frac{1}{n-1/2} = \frac{2}{2n-1}
$$
because the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ is strictly *convex* on $[n-1, n]$, so that the integral is larger than the area under the tangent at the point $x= n-1/2$.

[image]

Comment: You can't beat this answer for clarity and brevity. Thanks especially for the graph!

Comment: @PapaSmurf: You are welcome. – Btw, you can also interpret this as an application of Jensen's inequality to the convex function $\phi(x) = 1/x$: $\int_{n-1}^n \phi(x) \, dx \ge \phi \left( \int_{n-1}^n x \, dx\right) = \phi(n-1/2)$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standard way to show the inequality for $n>1$ only using a first derivative.

Setting $t = \frac 1{n-1} \Leftrightarrow n= 1+\frac 1t$ the inequality is equivalent with

$$\log(1+t) > \frac{2t}{t+2} \text{ for } t>0$$

or

$$f(t) := \log(1+t) -\frac{2t}{t+2}  > 0\text{ for } t>0$$

Now, $f(t)$ is defined at $t=0$ with $f(0) = 0$ and we only need to show that $f'(t) >0$ for $t>0$.

$$f'(t) = \frac 1{(1+t)} - \frac 4{(t+2)^2} >0 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\frac 1{(1+t)} > \frac 4{(t+2)^2} \Leftrightarrow (t+2)^2 > 4(1+t)$$
which is obvious for $t>0$.